# How to handle directory with spaces for azure file share rest api?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-rest-api

I am getting an error when using below script if the directory contains spaces. could someone please let me know how to handle spaces

```
$Version = "2017-04-17"
$AccessKey = 'xxxxx'
$storageAccount = 'xxxxx'
$ShareName = 'test'
$Directory = 'test dir'

$date = [System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("R",[Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)

$stringToSign = "PUT`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n`n"+
           "x-ms-date:$date`n" + "x-ms-meta-name:value`n" + "x-ms-version:$version`n" +
           "/$storageAccount/$ShareName/$Directory`ncomp:metadata`nrestype:directory" $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Convert]::FromBase64String($accesskey)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($stringToSign))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)

$headers=@{"x-ms-date"=$date;
           "x-ms-version"= $version;
           "Authorization"= "SharedKey $($storageAccount):$signature";
           "x-ms-meta-name"= "value"
           
                      
}
$URI = "https://$storageAccount.file.core.windows.net/$($ShareName)/$($Directory)?restype=directory&comp=metadata"

Invoke-WebRequest $URI -Method 'Put' -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing
```

Error is AuthenticationFailedServer failed to authenticate the request. M
ake sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the sig
nature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to use for space in REST URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610360/what-to-use-for-space-in-rest-uri)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding %20 instead of space in the value of $directory variable