# REST API: Correct verb and path to use for searching by a String that includes a space?

Tags: java, rest, http, spring-mvc, get

I want to implement a `REST` endpoint that gets all `Trainers` that match a certain name.

The name field is both first and last name, e.g. `Joe Bloggs`

Is the following implementation correct? What is a better alternative?

```
// v1/trainers/name/Joe Bloggs
@GetMapping("/v1/trainers/name/{trainerName}")
public List<TrainerDTO> findTrainersByName(@PathVariable String trainerName) {
    return trainerService.findTrainersByName(trainerName);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2610360/16735955).
**TLDR**: The common way to introduce the space (or equivalent) is to use spaces, escaped as %20 (Joe%20Blogs) or use dashes (Joe-Blogs).

Comment: Can you please share an example how it would work in my scenario as my string is one string with a space in the middle? also would I use query params rather than path params?